# Google maps API. Adding Markers

Tags: javascript, c#, html, arrays, json

I have updated my code so now the Map remains in tact when I add the script to place the markers. Unfortunately, The add markers instruction isn't working. The data containing the coordinates is pulled from SQL and converted to JSON using C# and stored as a Hidden Field. This in itself works as it should but I can't seem to get my Script to read the data and pass the info to the map  and drop the marker. Here is my code as it stands right now.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="locationData" />                  H<%--IDDEN FIELD CONTAINING DATA--%>
</form>
<div class="header">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">  

    function initMap() {
        var options = {                                                     //MAP LOAD OPTIONS
            zoom: 5.8,
            center: { lat: 54.251186, lng: -4.463196 }
        }
        var map = new
            google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);       //LOOADS MAP
        // Add Markers

        var markers;
        var arr = document.getElementById("LocationData");                  //CALLS HIDDEN FIELD AND SETS RULES FOR ADDING MARKERS TO THE MAP
        if (arr == "") {
            markers = {};
        }
        else {
            markers = $.parseJSON(arr.Latitude, arr.Longitude);
        };
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {                                    //LOOPS THROUGH THE DATA AND ADDS MARKER AS PER LAT AND LONG
            var data = markers[0];
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);   
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.building
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Mike

Comment: I have updated my code and my map now stays in tact. The code for adding markers as per the fata in the hidden File still doesn't work. Here is my code. What is it missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are viewing the above html response from asp on a web browser (Google Chrome), so I can help you debug the issue. On the Google chrome at the top right corner click on the '3 dots' (menu) then click on 'More Tools' then click on 'Developer Tools', which would by default open the 'Console' tab window and you can find the error(s) from your html code in 'red' color text. Try to analyze the error and also you can add more çonsole.log() or console.log('') in your JavaScript code, which can provide you more information and help you resolve the issue.